# Is it possible to split up the lib files from the war file, just like in executable jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jar, war

When I export a jar fle, I can specify that the lib files be stored in a folder `jarfilename_lib`. Is the same possible on `.war` files ?

This will save `99%` of my deployment time, I can just copy a small `war`, and I dont need to copy a heavy `war` file with all the `jar` library files.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible in most webapp containers.

The way it works is, you put your libraries into a shared directory in server, and the libraries will be visible to every webapp deployed.

For example, in tomcat it's [/lib](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Shared_Library_Files) directory.

Comment: How do I build a WAR without the jars, and only my code ?

Comment: Just don't place them in WEB-INF/lib directory when you build your WAR. If you use Maven, you can use skinny-war feature: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html